# Date_Range parameters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to apply a date_range to the index of my dataframe that comes as datetime, for which I want the hours, days, months to be added in said index according to a duration hour value.

**Ex: Original Dataframe**

```
  Date_Out                Hour_Duration
2020-04-10 06:19:45            3
2020-04-19 20:05:50            6
2020-04-30 22:50:00            4
```

**Ex: Dataframe Desired Result**

```
 Date_Out                Hour_Duration
2020-04-10 06:19:45            3
2020-04-19 07:19:45            3
2020-04-19 08:19:45            3
2020-04-19 20:05:50            6
2020-04-19 21:05:50            6
2020-04-19 22:05:50            6
2020-04-19 23:05:50            6
2020-04-20 00:05:50            6
2020-04-20 01:05:50            6
2020-04-30 22:50:00            4
2020-04-30 23:50:00            4
2020-05-01 00:50:00            4
2020-05-01 01:50:00            4
```

What solution do you recommend? Can a function be applied in the "period" parameter of the date_range?

**UPDATE:**

Original Dataframe (Name Dataframe: travels)

```
        Date    Actual Departure Date    Arrival Date     DurationHour  DHour
0   2020-04-28  2020-04-28 12:26:39 2020-04-28 16:24:00 0 days 03:57:21   3
1   2020-04-20  2020-04-20 07:53:22 2020-04-21 05:30:00 0 days 21:36:38   6
2   2020-05-28  2020-05-28 15:54:22 2020-05-29 08:17:00 0 days 16:22:38   2
3   2020-05-29  2020-05-29 22:57:05 2020-05-30 01:21:00 0 days 02:23:55   5
4   2020-05-25  2020-05-25 07:22:41 2020-05-30 13:47:00 5 days 06:24:19   1
```

`travels.dtypes`

```
Date                      datetime64[ns]
Actual Departure Date     datetime64[ns]
Arrival Date              datetime64[ns]
DurationHour              timedelta64[ns]
DHour                           int64
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

The result is reflected in the column `Actual Departure Date`, where the unit sum of hours in the column  `Actual Departure Date` is conditional (*repeats and adds an hour*) on the value of the column `DHour`

```
     Date   Actual Departure Date    Arrival Date         DurationHour    DHour
0   2020-04-28  2020-04-28 12:26:39 2020-04-28 16:24:00 0 days 03:57:21     3
0   2020-04-28  2020-04-28 13:26:39 2020-04-28 16:24:00 0 days 03:57:21     3
0   2020-04-28  2020-04-28 14:26:39 2020-04-28 16:24:00 0 days 03:57:21     3
0   2020-04-28  2020-04-28 15:26:39 2020-04-28 16:24:00 0 days 03:57:21     3
1   2020-04-20  2020-04-20 07:53:22 2020-04-21 05:30:00 0 days 21:36:38     6
1   2020-04-20  2020-04-20 08:53:22 2020-04-21 05:30:00 0 days 21:36:38     6
1   2020-04-20  2020-04-20 09:53:22 2020-04-21 05:30:00 0 days 21:36:38     6
1   2020-04-20  2020-04-20 10:53:22 2020-04-21 05:30:00 0 days 21:36:38     6
1   2020-04-20  2020-04-20 11:53:22 2020-04-21 05:30:00 0 days 21:36:38     6
1   2020-04-20  2020-04-20 12:53:22 2020-04-21 05:30:00 0 days 21:36:38     6
1   2020-04-20  2020-04-20 13:53:22 2020-04-21 05:30:00 0 days 21:36:38     6
2   2020-05-28  2020-05-28 15:54:22 2020-05-29 08:17:00 0 days 16:22:38     2
2   2020-05-28  2020-05-28 16:54:22 2020-05-29 08:17:00 0 days 16:22:38     2
2   2020-05-28  2020-05-28 16:54:22 2020-05-29 08:17:00 0 days 16:22:38     2
3   2020-05-29  2020-05-29 23:57:05 2020-05-30 01:21:00 0 days 02:23:55     5
3   2020-05-29  2020-05-30 00:57:05 2020-05-30 01:21:00 0 days 02:23:55     5
3   2020-05-29  2020-05-30 01:57:05 2020-05-30 01:21:00 0 days 02:23:55     5
3   2020-05-29  2020-05-30 02:57:05 2020-05-30 01:21:00 0 days 02:23:55     5
3   2020-05-29  2020-05-30 03:57:05 2020-05-30 01:21:00 0 days 02:23:55     5
3   2020-05-29  2020-05-30 04:57:05 2020-05-30 01:21:00 0 days 02:23:55     5
4   2020-05-25  2020-05-25 07:22:41 2020-05-30 13:47:00 5 days 06:24:19     1
4   2020-05-25  2020-05-25 08:22:41 2020-05-30 13:47:00 5 days 06:24:19     1
```

I am trying the following method: `travels.loc[np.repeat(travels.index.values, abs(travels['DHour']))]` and it repeats correctly but I do not achieve the desired sum in the date and time of the column `Actual Departure Date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this we using list comprehension and pd.concat:

```
df = df.set_index('Date_Out')
pd.concat(
    [
        df.reindex(
            pd.date_range(idx, periods=row["Hour_Duration"], freq="H"),
            fill_value=row["Hour_Duration"],
        )
        for idx, row in df.iterrows()
    ]
)
```

Output:

```
                     Hour_Duration
2020-04-10 06:19:45              3
2020-04-10 07:19:45              3
2020-04-10 08:19:45              3
2020-04-19 20:05:50              6
2020-04-19 21:05:50              6
2020-04-19 22:05:50              6
2020-04-19 23:05:50              6
2020-04-20 00:05:50              6
2020-04-20 01:05:50              6
2020-04-30 22:50:00              4
2020-04-30 23:50:00              4
2020-05-01 00:50:00              4
2020-05-01 01:50:00              4
```

---

#### Update new data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

input_text = StringIO("""        Date    Actual Departure Date    Arrival Date     DurationHour    DHour
0   2020-04-28  2020-04-28 12:26:39  2020-04-28 16:24:00  0 days 03:57:21   3
1   2020-04-20  2020-04-20 07:53:22  2020-04-21 05:30:00  0 days 21:36:38   6
2   2020-05-28  2020-05-28 15:54:22  2020-05-29 08:17:00  0 days 16:22:38   2
3   2020-05-29  2020-05-29 22:57:05  2020-05-30 01:21:00  0 days 02:23:55   5
4   2020-05-25  2020-05-25 07:22:41  2020-05-30 13:47:00  5 days 06:24:19   1""")

df = pd.read_csv(input_text, sep= '\s\s+', engine='python')

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df.set_index('Date')
df_out = pd.concat(
            [
                df.reindex(
                    pd.date_range(idx, periods=row["DHour"], freq="H"),
                )
                for idx, row in df.iterrows()
             ]
         ).ffill()
```

Output:

```
                    Actual Departure Date         Arrival Date     DurationHour  DHour
2020-04-28 00:00:00   2020-04-28 12:26:39  2020-04-28 16:24:00  0 days 03:57:21    3.0
2020-04-28 01:00:00   2020-04-28 12:26:39  2020-04-28 16:24:00  0 days 03:57:21    3.0
2020-04-28 02:00:00   2020-04-28 12:26:39  2020-04-28 16:24:00  0 days 03:57:21    3.0
2020-04-20 00:00:00   2020-04-20 07:53:22  2020-04-21 05:30:00  0 days 21:36:38    6.0
2020-04-20 01:00:00   2020-04-20 07:53:22  2020-04-21 05:30:00  0 days 21:36:38    6.0
2020-04-20 02:00:00   2020-04-20 07:53:22  2020-04-21 05:30:00  0 days 21:36:38    6.0
2020-04-20 03:00:00   2020-04-20 07:53:22  2020-04-21 05:30:00  0 days 21:36:38    6.0
2020-04-20 04:00:00   2020-04-20 07:53:22  2020-04-21 05:30:00  0 days 21:36:38    6.0
2020-04-20 05:00:00   2020-04-20 07:53:22  2020-04-21 05:30:00  0 days 21:36:38    6.0
2020-05-28 00:00:00   2020-05-28 15:54:22  2020-05-29 08:17:00  0 days 16:22:38    2.0
2020-05-28 01:00:00   2020-05-28 15:54:22  2020-05-29 08:17:00  0 days 16:22:38    2.0
2020-05-29 00:00:00   2020-05-29 22:57:05  2020-05-30 01:21:00  0 days 02:23:55    5.0
2020-05-29 01:00:00   2020-05-29 22:57:05  2020-05-30 01:21:00  0 days 02:23:55    5.0
2020-05-29 02:00:00   2020-05-29 22:57:05  2020-05-30 01:21:00  0 days 02:23:55    5.0
2020-05-29 03:00:00   2020-05-29 22:57:05  2020-05-30 01:21:00  0 days 02:23:55    5.0
2020-05-29 04:00:00   2020-05-29 22:57:05  2020-05-30 01:21:00  0 days 02:23:55    5.0
2020-05-25 00:00:00   2020-05-25 07:22:41  2020-05-30 13:47:00  5 days 06:24:19    1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried to apply your solution but it throws the following error: **ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis**

Comment: You have duplicate 'Date_Out' you'll need to groupby.   If you post a small dataset that duplicates this error, I will attempt to rewrite a solution.

Comment: I have done an update to the question, with the original dataframe and the expected result